# ios facebook get friendlist who play the same app

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-friends

I can get the friendlist by

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];
```

But the list contain all the friends, how could I get the friendlist that only played the app.

Answer (score 3):

You can query the OpenGraph for the field installed:

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends?fields=installed,name"
                                             andParams:params
                                         andHttpMethod:httpMethod
                                           andDelegate:delegate];
```

That will return you a list of friends, in which some will have the field installed=1

Comment: Hi Angel, I have the same problem but can't understand in this answer that.. for which application "fields=installed" will check. I mean, we are not giving any appId here then how can we be sure that in the response installed=1 is for my application.Please help me.

Comment: Well, you are giving the appId when login. The facebook object used is logged within that app.

Answer (score 1):

This gives you a list of your friends that have the app installed

friend.getAppUsers()